# Get the autocompletion popup to appear when typing in the text editor

Tags: xcode

Like Visual Studio, I want the code completion menu to popup immediately after I start typing.

I don't mean the completion inline - I mean I want the same window that popups when you press esc to appear.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code completion settings are in Xcode Preferences (shortcut: command-comma) -> Code Sense. I don't think you can make the actual pop-up list (as oppose to the completion line) appear without hitting escape.